# Retrive Data fromJSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML that I parse into a JSON and put it into an array. So I got the following:

```
{
    "result": {
        "stats": {
            "count":"0"
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to retrieve data from the array trying the following:

```
$yummy = json_decode($json);
echo $yummy->count; //0
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why convert XML to JSON if you can't process the JSON.  Why not stick with the XML and learn to use SimpleXML.

Comment: @luca you should check you json structure and then access it echo $yummy->result->stats->count;

Comment: Note the structure when it's formatted better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns a mixed variable, you can force it to return an associative array by passing a second argument true :

`$yummy = json_decode($json, true);`

Then you can access your values as in an array :
`echo $yummy['result']['stats']['count'];`

Answer (score 0):

The object only has one property and it is called `result` not `count`.

You can't access a random property at any point in the data structure from the top level. You have to work your way down through all the ancestors of the data you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

Converting XML to JSON means that you will loose information and features. The conversion is not needed, actually. SimpleXML provides comparable syntax, while with DOM you can use Xpath expressions.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<response>
  <result>
    <stats>
      <count>21</count>
    </stats>
  </result>
</response>
XML;

// SimpleXML maps elements to properties
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump(
  (int)$response->result->stats->count
);

// DOM can use Xpath expressions to extract values
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('number(/response/result/stats/count)')
);
```

Output:

```
int(21)
float(21)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use some [online json validator](https://jsonlint.com) to make sure your parsed json is correct.

Comment: The question isn't about valid JSON it's about how to access the contents.